# CSS Padding not working in on html5 web page

Tags: css, padding

I have been searching for an answer to this for some time.
i want to add space to the bottom of my web page, as content sits too close to edge.
I have tied 'padding-bottom' in wrapper tag, in body tag and in style tag.. not working.
any help on this appreciated..

thanks,
Keith.

http://www.reddogonline.eu/av.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're positioning relatively all your elements. That's causing the padding/margin problems too. Why would you position your elements like this?
Try removing relative positioning and add top/bottom margins to your elements. The results will be the same in terms of visual effect.
It will also be much simpler adding new sound boxes, as you don't have to calculate a top positioning for each one.

Comment: I am using this method because until now I didn't know any other way.

Comment: I recommend you look for some tutorials on CSS positioning. It's not very complicated. I'm sure you'll get better with practice.

Comment: Strangely enough, I have been researching the css positioning, and it's a brick wall to me... no  explation so far has actually made it clear. relative is relative to what? static/fixed/absolute=same thing?anyway, thanks for your help, my pages now work as i want.. K.

Comment: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/ this helped me a lot some time ago, although I believe best way to learn css positioning is by trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

you have a serious design problem.

all your elements are relatively position with `top` offset, that cause the `wrapper` and `body` to be actually smaller then you think. because this offset is not taken in consideration when determining the wrapper height. (so the height of the wrapper is only the sum of his children height, without the offset between them)

when you add `padding-bottom` to the wrapper or the body, it works (of course), but you don't see it. because your elements overlaps the wrapper..

you will be able to see that I'm right by setting `overflow:hidden;` to the wrapper (or inspecting your site with a tool). suddenly, half of your content disappears..

you need to remove the `position:relative;` from your elements, and use `margin-top` instead of `top` to make the desired space between the elements.

That way: the wrapper and body height will be set right, and the padding will work as you expect it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just let your content flow naturally first, then accommodate it with margins. NOT with positioning. You are going deeper and deeper with the TOP property as you go down. Shouldn't be like this. Go with the flow. Your design isn't complex as far as positioning. Margins can do the job.

Comment: works great, thanks again.. further to this, should i use the same system for positioning the text divs within the video divs?

Comment: i clicked the tick to green - is that the way?